# Automate the execution of a SQL script based on cell value in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I am looking to automate the following process:
when a cell value = "particularValue" in GoogleSheet ---> execute a SQL script ---> Export a CSV.

We can do that with VBA for Excel. The equivalent For GSheet is Google Apps Script.
Can someone share a GAS code that would run a SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

This can be performed with VBA. Open "view code" for sheet and enter this subroutine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = "particularValue" Then 
        ' do something
    end if
End Sub
```

I will need more specifics about the SQL connection etc. for the CSV - but that question has been asked elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will check if the VBA option is available in Google sheet . The last part for csv, I will use the function export data options in the SQL script.

Comment: If you are using google sheets, you should not tag your post as [Excel]